# Como Anexas dos Diccionarios de Python a otro diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

Soy nuevo en Python

pero tengo una matriz de varias columnas la columna 0 tiene (01/02/18 hasta 28/02/1) la columna en la columna 2 tengo ( '8-6 ENL TIC-DZT', '4-2 ENL PLD-STA-NRI', '6-12 ENL ALT-TMO', '_0-16 MALPASODOS-TABASCO', '3-1 ENL MAN', '4-7 CHO 400-230', '4-10 SCP-HGA', '8-9 ENL VAD-CNC', '2-2 ENL LAV-TCL LAV-PBD', '_0-4 ENL LCP_PIT DOG CRP', '_0-22 ENL HERMOSILLO-SIN', '8-10 ENL)

```
dic_Enlace={}
dic_Fecha={}

   for i in range(len(HST)):
    dic_Fecha[HST[i][0]]={}
    #print dic_Fecha

    for j in range(len(HST)):
    dic_Enlace[HST[j][2]]={}
    #print dic_Enlace
```

quería meter estos dos diccionarios a el siguiente dic_MEM

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Horacio. Falta información a tu pregunta. Dado que los diccionarios usan tablas hash y no permiten repeticiones "meter dos diccionarios a otro diccionario"  tiene varias aproximaciones. ¿Tienen ambos diccionarios claves comunes?¿En el caso anterior que debe ocurrir? Sería oportuno que agregaras un [mcve] con dos diccionarios de partida de ejemplo (incluso un ejemplo del contenido de HST) y con el diccionario de salida que esperas obtener dados esos dos diccionarios. Usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/139096/edit) para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Horacio te recomiendo explicar que entradas tienes y que salida deseas para tu problema concreto, como dice @FJSevilla debes proveer un [mcve], es decir tu codigo debe ser minimo.

Comment: Sigues sin mostrar que esperas obtener de salida y tampoco la entrada, por lo que no tenemos forma de reproducir el problema. Por favor agrega una entrada y la salida esperada (unas cuantas filas del excel incluida cabecera y el diccionario que quieres como resultado sería suficiente). Además, si agregaras más información a la pregunta indicando cual es la finalidad de lo que pretendes (parece que estas tratando con un GUI de wxWidgets por los imports) es posible que  pudiéramos orientar mejor ya que cabe la posibilidad de que se pueda vectorizar con Pandas/NumPy.

Comment: Te aconsejo que te tomes algo de tiempo en redactar correctamente tu pregunta, explicando la situación, el problema concreto y proporcionando lo necesario para reproducirlo. El tiempo que inviertas seguramente será recompensado ya que permitirá que recibas mejores respuestas y más rápidamente. Nosotros no tenemos la información que tu tienes, solo sabemos que cargas un Excel (sin saber su estructura o contenido) y parece que intentas crear dos diccionarios con los datos de dos columnas...

Comment: Gracias lo que sucede es que soy nuevo en Python lo que hice es hacer dos diccionarios el primero(dic_fecha={}) lo llene del a siguiente manera for i in range(len(hst)):   dic_Fecha[HST[i][0]={} y luego llene el diccionario dic_Enlaces ya teniendo los dos diccionarios quería meter estos 2 diccionarios en otro diccionario se puede?

Comment: Si quieres crear otro diccionario: `nuevo_dict = {"dict1": dict1, "dict2" : dict2}`

Comment: muchas gracias me ha servido mucho

Answer (score 1):

La funcionalidad de un diccionario en python es la de key -> value, es decir, a cada clave (las keys no pueden ser listas o diccionarios) se le asigna un valor (que puede ser cualquier cosa, incluso otro diccionario, de hecho, un valor guardado en un diccionario puede ser sí mismo).

Si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer (sería útil que agregaras más información, como ya te comentaron, tu pregunta está incompleta), una manera de organizar mejor la información sería:

```
{
  FECHA1: [
    HORA1,
    HORA2,
    HORA3,
  ],
  FECHA2: [
    HORA1,
    HORA2,
    HORA3,
  ],
}
```

Un ejemplo de este formato sería:

```
{
  "01/02/2018": [
     "8-6 ENL TIC-DZT",
     "4-2 ENL PLD-STA-NRI",
  ],

  "05/02/2018": [
    "2-2 ENL LAV-TCL LAV-PBD",
    "_0-22 ENL HERMOSILLO-SIN',
  ],
}
```

Para generar un diccionario con esta estructura a partir de la información como tú la tienes:

```
informacion = {}

for i in range(len(HTS)):
    informacion[HST[i][0]] = []  # Creamos la lista con la informacion asociada a la fecha

    for hora in HTS[i][2]:
        informacion[HST[i][0]].append(hora)  # Agregamos las horas a la lista recien creada
```

Obviamente puedes trabajar con los dos diccionarios como lo venías haciendo.
Para "agregar" esa información al diccionario dic_MEM:

Si trabajas con un diccionario:

```
dic_MEM["informacion"] = informacion  # El diccionario del ejemplo
print(dic_MEM["informacion"])  # Con 'dic_MEM["informacion"]' podras acceder al diccionario con toda la informacion
```

Si trabajas con dos diccionarios:

```
dic_MEM["enlaces"] = dic_Enlaces
dic_MEM["fechas"] = dic_Fechas
print(dic_MEM["enlaces"])  # Con 'dic_MEM["enlaces"]' podras acceder a dic_Enlaces
print(dic_MEM["fechas"])  # Con 'dic_MEM["fechas"]' podras acceder a dic_Fechas
```

Nuevamente, no queda muy claro qué quieres obtener (la salida) ni cuál es el proposito de 'dic_Enlaces', así que puede que esta respuesta no se ajuste del todo a lo que buscas.